# How to autofit table's row height in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I want a table to fill a page entirely, firstly I can find an **AutoFit Window** option to fit the table's column width, where can I auto fit the table's height to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just create a fixed row height until the table filled the page.  To do that, highlight the row and go to the Layout tab.

[image]

To create a custom template so you don't have to do that each time, highlight the table, go to the "Insert" ribbon and click on "Quick Parts". At the bottom of the menu, "Save Selection to Quick Part Gallery".

[image]

Make sure you change the gallery from Quick Parts to Tables and create a unique name for it:

[image]

So each time you need a single-cell page that covers the entire page, go to the "Insert" tab and select the "Table" icon.  Run your cursor over "Quick Tables" at the bottom of the menu and scroll to the appropriate table.  You can also save it to the table style gallery from there.

[image]

Comment: Can you describe it a bit more? Single-line answers rarely get far here

Comment: This solution is a clumsy if you have more than one row in the table.

Comment: Elderry was looking for a solution for a table to take up the entirety of the page. So I provided a solution that would easily accomplish that assuming that it was a single-cell table.  I would also suggest saving the table format as a template for easy access if it's going to be used often enough. I'll add that as an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this but the process isn't pretty but it does work.

1. Create a text box the size of the page and insert the table into it.
2. Highlight the table and from the Layout menu on the ribbon press Text Direction until the arrows on the button are pointing down. The text in your table should be oriented from the top to bottom instead of left to right.
3. From table settings autofit the table to window (or make the table column width 100%).
4. Select the textbox only and rotate it 90 degrees to the left. The
   result should be a table that grows downward to fit inside the
   texbox and "autofits" the row height. Word does "auto rotate" the
   textbox back up right while you are editing so editing the table
   contents might be a pain, I haven't found any way to disable this.